# Capturing a copy event in Firefox Plugin

Tags: javascript, firefox, event-handling, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Hi I am new to firefox plugins and js and have no concrete idea of how things work. I am trying to capture any user initiated copy event either by key board or by context menu. 
As I read some posts([How to capture copy events on arbitrary web pages in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314587/how-to-capture-copy-events-on-arbitrary-web-pages-in-javascript)) I understand there is a copy event which needs to be captured and handled as per my requirements. What I am unable to figure out is how to capture this event. In particular to what is the event related to. 
On a similar note I tried working with user selection as per 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Add_a_Context_Menu_Item and 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/selection
While this worked fine for me I am confused of what API I should use.

I was trying to add a `EventListener` on `gBrowser` via `gBrowser.addEventListener("copy", function(){console.log("copy event");}, true);` while it errors out saying `gBrowser not defined`
Also I tried with `window.addEventListener("copy",function(){console.log("copy event");}, true);` which also returns that window is not defined. I guess I am missing on some import or initialization. Any links in this regards will be helpful.

Comment: Joshua, SO is not a code outsourcing site nor is it a "I don't know what I am doing so just tell me site".  Instead you should learn the basics through research, classes, or peers and then share with us your existing code and where in that code you are stuck.

Comment: Sorry @Chrismas007 for putting it this way, I did try for capturing "copy" event and read the MDN docs but was unable to figure out what went wrong. I was trying to add a EventListener on gBrowser gBrowser.addEventListener("copy", function(){console.log("copy event");}, true); while it errors out saying gBrowser not defined.

Comment: Then you should edit your original post to include that code and the code surrounding it so people can help you with your error.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/51b62b356b3a21010a4d ill post some code for you

Comment: I understand your trouble @joshua extension development is very tricky to learn because of the tricky scoping issues. Your question is perfectly fine. SO is a great place and is meant to start new comers off. If you can't do it here then where can you right?

Comment: Yes @Noitidart thanks for the elaborate link. I was trying with the addon sdk's while that talked of the bootstrap method. If I am correctly reading addon sdk's is the new way for extension development and was trying for it.

Comment: It's a new way but its designed for beginners. SDK just taps into bootstrap with high level api's. Bootstrap is on your own stuff no help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this code works, run it from scratchpad.

Set the devloper preferences: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Development_preferences

Open scratchpad: Shift + F4

Paste this code:

```
function cevent(e) {
  console.log('copied, e:', e);
}
gBrowser.addEventListener('copy', cevent, false)
```

Click the menu item in scratchpad called "Environment" and then click "Browser".

Then click "Run"

then copy something in the most recent browser you used, this code added this event listener just to the most recent window.

You'll see an even log in browser console:
[image]

you can see there is paste and cut and other events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.onpaste?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.onpaste

Comment: Some how in my case it still says gBrowser not defined. I am missing on something. Is there some other initialization as well which i think i have skipped although I went through the MDN's link.

Comment: Make sure to set the devleopment preferences so you use the scratchpad and see the messages in browser soncole. You have to make sure to set environment menu to browser.  Open browser console with ctrl + shift + j. In place of `gBrowser` you can do `Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').gBrowser`